# How can I import a data file as a variable?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a somewhat non-standard need where I need to store a large blob of data in a text file, and import it into svelte. Currently, my object looks like this

```
<script>
let data = "A very large string";
</string>

<div>
{data}
</div>
```

I want to store the contents of data as a string, which is dynamically compiled into the object, e.g.

```
<script>
let data = import("myData.txt");
</string>

<div>
{data}
</div>
```

I Can't see anything in the svelte documentation that says this is supported, but I'm new to svelte / front-end dev, so maybe someone can suggest a workaround?

Comment: What kind of data is inside the file?

Comment: For all intensive purposes, text, but the type really shouldn't matter.

Comment: okay, my answer should solve your issue, hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

Store the large blob of data inside a `.txt` file on the server at a location where it can be publicly accessed, and then use `fetch()` to load it from there.

```js
let data = await fetch('https://localhost/public_path/myData.txt')
  .then(res => res.text());
```

**Note:** I have no experience with `svelte`

All the best.

Comment: That works, and we've started to do that for now, but it's certainly sub-optimal as it requires subsequent requests for each component (in addition to dealing with async) but for now it works, thanks!

Comment: If you're loading the same file multiple times, then consider caching it in the user's storage where necessary.

Comment: Fetch is better in this use case, importing a text file in your js will end up increasing the bundle size.

Comment: Wih Vite you can import json. https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#json